# Performing a union in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to get the union of these two queries but keep getting the following error:

```
'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and    the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Union<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments
```

The linq queries look like this:

```
var g = from p in context.APP_PROD_COMP_tbl
        where p.FAM_MFG == fam_mfg
        group p by new
        {
            a_B_G = p.B_G,
            a_MFG = p.MFG,
            a_PRODUCT_FAM = p.PRODUCT_FAM,
        };

var q = from p in context.APP_COMP_tbl
        where p.FAM_MFG == fam_mfg
        group p by new
        {

            a_B_G = p.a_B_G,
            a_MFG = p.a_MFG,
            a_PRODUCT_FAM = p.a_PRODUCT_FAM,

        };

var data = q.Union(g);
```

I've tried using IEnumerable around the queries, but it still didn't work. Not really sure where I'm going wrong at this point, although admittedly LINQ isn't something I've had a ton of exposure to.

**Update:**

So I've gone in a slightly different direction from what I posted earlier. After doing more research, the `group by` statements were from old code and no longer needed for the intended purpose. I changed those to `select new` statements and had no further issue with the union.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem here is type mismatch: `g` is of type `IGrouping<AnonymousType#1, APP_PROD_COMP_tbl>` and `q` is of type `IGrouping<AnonymousType#1, APP_COMP_tbl>`; this is why `Union` gives you the error.

I am not really sure what you are trying to `Union` (keys of the groups or groups of data themselves) but the solution would be:

If you want to union group keys, select the keys of your groups

```
var data = g.Select(x => x.Key).Union(q.Select(x => x.Key));
```

If you want to union the groups themselves then you need to project each element from both sequences into a common type, perform the grouping and then union the groups

```
var g = context.APP_PROD_COMP_tbl
    .Where(p => p.FAM_MFG == fam_mfg)
    .Select(ToCommonType)   
    .GroupBy(p => new
    {
        a_B_G = p.B_G,
        a_MFG = p.MFG,
        a_PRODUCT_FAM = p.PRODUCT_FAM,
    });

var q = context.APP_COMP_tbl
    .Where(p => p.FAM_MFG == fam_mfg)
    .Select(ToCommonType)
    .GroupBy(p => new
    {

        a_B_G = p.a_B_G,
        a_MFG = p.a_MFG,
        a_PRODUCT_FAM = p.a_PRODUCT_FAM,

    });

var data = g.Union(q);

private CommonClass ToCommonType(APP_PROD_COMP_tbl item)
{
    return new CommonClass
    {
    };
}

private CommonClass ToCommonType(APP_COMP_tbl item)
{
    return new CommonClass
    {
    };
}
```

Comment: I explored going in this direction until I realized that the group by statements were unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your Anonymouse types don't match:

```
 var a = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => new {a = x}).AsQueryable();
 var b = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => new {b = x}).AsQueryable();
 var c = a.Union(b);
```

This won't work because typeof `a` is not same as typeof `b`

```
 var a = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => new {a = x}).AsQueryable();
 var b = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => new {a = x}).AsQueryable();
 var c = a.Union(b);
```

But this will work, because Anonymouse types are the same.

You can try selecting same anonymouse types from your collection in `q` and `g`. Read more about [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156049.aspx) for IQueryable

Union on `IQueryAble<TSource>()` accepts `IQueryAble<TSource>` as a parameter, so collection has to be the same type.

Comment: @downvoter please explain why this is a bad solution?

Comment: I see that his anonymous object match, unless the types don't match I don't see what you're suggesting.

Comment: @TombMedia I'm suggesting that APP_PROD_COMP_tbl!=APP_COMP_tbl so group of that objects won't match and union won't work

Comment: The source shouldn't matter as long as the types for a_B_G, a_MFG, and a_PRODUCT_FAM match. Has nothing to do with queryable.

Comment: nope, because he groups data as APP_PROD_COMP_tbl and APP_COMP_tbl, there is no select, so underlying objects in groups are different types, you can not union different types (no matter if it's list, enumerable or queryable)